# ¿Por qué mi proyecto se ve todo en blanco?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

estoy trabajando con React Native y expo, tengo que hacer un WebView pero al momento de insertar el url en el atributo source, no me muestra nada al momento de compilarlo. La verdad ya intenté todo para que se visualice en mi navegador, cabe destacar que con expo puedes ver el renderizado ya sea en el navegador o en el celular, así que todo lo veo a través de mi celular, por ejemplo el (h1) que aparece en el código si se logra visualizar, lo que no se ve es el WebView, de hecho no funciona con ninguna URL, alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor, ya llevo dos días con este problema.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
 },
});

export default function App(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <Text>Test text</Text>
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: 'https://www.youtube.com' }}
    />
    </View>
   );
}
```

Aquí está mi package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "expo start",
  "android": "expo start --android",
  "ios": "expo start --ios",
  "web": "expo start --web",
  "eject": "expo eject"
},
"dependencies": {
  "expo": "~41.0.1",
  "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
  "react": "17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "17.0.2",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
  "react-native-web": "~0.16.3",
  "react-native-webview": "11.2.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.14.3"
},
"private": true
```

Comment: ¿Intentaste darle ancho y alto al webview?

Comment: Si así es y no funcionó...

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciono de esta forma:

```
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <WebView style = {{width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height}} source={{ uri: "https://www.google.com" }}  />
    </View>
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).